# Why is TS throwing this error "Argument of type 'MyMedicine[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MyMedicine'."?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, mean-stack

I have a interface:

```
export interface MyMedicine {
_id: String;
name: String;
quantity: Number;
time: String;
```

}

This is my angular service to post data:

```
postMed(newMed): Observable<MyMedicine[]>{
var headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return this.http.post<MyMedicine[]>(`${this.url}/api/medicine`, newMed, {headers:headers});
```

}

This is my component with addmedicine() to post data on submitting a form:

```
addmedicine(){
const newMedicine = {
  name: this.name,
  quantity: this.quantity,
  time: this.time
};
this.medService.postMed(newMedicine)
    .subscribe(medicine =>{
      this.medicines.push(medicine);
    })}
```

I get an error message saying "Argument of type 'MyMedicine[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MyMedicine'.
Type 'MyMedicine[]' is missing the following properties from type 'MyMedicine': _id, name, quantity, time"

I have imported the interface and service in my component. Dependency injection has been taken care of. _id is the default id to be generated by MongoDB.

Comment: Could you try with `this.medicines = [...this.medicines, ...medicine]` ?

Comment: @VLAZ It's the other way around. `postMed` returns an array of elements, and `this.medicines.push` expects a single element.

Comment: @Emilien I tried your method and I get an error "Type 'MyMedicine[]' is missing the following properties from type 'MyMedicine': _id, name, quantity, time"

Answer (score 0):

As we tell you in comments above, the problem is that you receive from `this.medService.postMed` an array of `MyMedicine`.

One of the solutions is to add only the last item from the array you receive.

```
medicines: MyMedicines[];

this.medService.postMed(newMedicine).subscribe(medicines => this.medicines.push(medicines.pop()))
```

Comment: Thanks @Emilien. Now there is no error, but nothing updates to the DB. I have tested my API in Postman and it works.

Answer (score 0):

As HTTP post request returns only the newly added item to the MyMedicines[] array modify postMed method as below:

```
postMed(newMed): Observable<MyMedicine>{
var headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return this.http.post<MyMedicine>(`${this.url}/api/medicine`, newMed, {headers:headers});
```

and then in component class, consume the observable which is emitted by HTTP post request as below :

```
addmedicine(){
const newMedicine = {
  name: this.name,
  quantity: this.quantity,
  time: this.time
};
this.medService.postMed(newMedicine)
    .subscribe((medicine : MyMedicine) =>{
      this.medicines.push(medicine);
    })}
```

Please check from your side if it is working.